# parsing command line args that has same key - java

Tags: java, command-line-interface

In my Java Program, I have to call the main method of another jar file, that accepts the following.
`-set Options:CL=1

-set Options:CI=ABC

-set Options:IsCompresed=1

-fileLocation C:\text.txt`

How do I achieve this having -set as a common key.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the main method of another jar file"? Executing external java process running that another jar file or invoking directly the main method of the class from that jar file (which is in your classpath)?

Answer (score 0):

While running the jar file using command line, arguments can be passed which get set to the args array in main(String args[]) they can be assigned to variables.

```
java -jar test.jar argument1 argument2
```

Comment: I am looking to write something in my Java Code, not command line, such that its gets all those args and send to another java app that accepts these args.